# Laravel Broadcasting and Queues

Tags: laravel, queue, broadcast, pusher

I am developing a app to process videos. I try to push 10 videos into a queue. After a video was processed I fired a event like this:

```
...
$production->render();

event(new VideoHasProcessed(basename($this->video->path)));
...
```

And I do following this video to push a notification to users (https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/12)

The problem is: I want to push a notification when each video was processed but in fact, after 10 videos was processed the notification was displayed.

This is my script:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_ID, {
            encrypted: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('test');

        channel.bind('App\\Events\\VideoHasProcessed', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

**Update:**

Dispatch a job

```
foreach ($request->input('files') as $file)
    {
        ...

        // Dispatch a job.
        $this->dispatch(new ProduceVideo($video));

        ....
    }
```

And my job class:

public function handle(ProductionRepository $production)
{
    ...

```
$production->render();

event(new VideoHasProcessed(basename($this->video->path)));

...
```

}

Answer (score 4):

After digging into laravel 5.3 core I found out the solution. You event class needs to extend ShouldBrodcastNow interface:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class MyEvent implements ShouldBrodcastNow
{
...
}
```

In that way if you need the event to be broadcasted right away, this should do the trick.

NOTE: there is not need for `MyEvent` to implement both interfaces `(ShouldBroadcastNow, ShouldBroadcast)` because the interface `ShouldBroadcastNow` already extends `ShouldBroadcast`

Comment: This is what I was looking for as I wanted my pusher event to be much more responsive as it was being fired from an already queued backend job.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your 10 videos are processed as separate queued jobs you'll just need to fire your event in each queued job. Here's an example handle function for a job class (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#job-class-structure):

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 */
public function handle()
{
    // Your video processing script

    // Fire your event
    event(new VideoHasProcessed(basename($this->video->path)));
}
```

If your videos are processed as 1 job you'll need to add your event inside any loop you may be using to process each video:

```
foreach($videos as $video):
    // Your video processing script

    // Fire your event
    event(new VideoHasProcessed(basename($this->video->path)));
endforeach;
```

Comment: I have fired my event in each queued job already. But it still display notification when 10 videos processed. I just added more code in my post.

Comment: Even when I add 1 video into queue and the first video is processing I add 1 more video, it still doest not push separate notification. When 2 videos is processed 2 notifications is pushed together.

Comment: What does the `render()` method do?